# keyboard that reacts strangely

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a WASD brand keyboard that seems to work well and has for years. I have tested it on several PC's and it specifically does this on my main windows 10 PC. This is what it does:

- When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, it puts my computer into deep sleep
- When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Gr</kbd>, it launches the calculator.
- When I press the menu key, it starts the shutdown proces.

I think the error will probably come from an application that listens to this keyboard since the other keyboards don't do it. The other keyboards are azerty keyboards and the WASD is a qwerty.

I'm looking for a way to correct my problem.
Do you have any idea where this problem is coming from?

Comment: What is the keyboard layout locale and which did you choose in the OS?

Comment: on the keyboard that has a problem I was in English Internationnal which until then worked very well

Comment: (1) What model is this keyboard? (2) Have you used it before, and have you installed an application for it? (3) Do you have AutoHotKey installed?

Comment: 1) wasd model v2
2) I have been using it for several years
3) nope

Comment: As you state, the issue is caused either by an app on your PC, or a setting in the OS itself. 1. Does the PC with the issue have installed Auto HotKey, Clavier+ or similar tool that remaps key presses? 2. Are you using a *Start Menu* alternative, such as *Open-Shel*l? 3. Is there a specific driver for the WASD keyboard installed? 4. Do you have Windows *Accessibility* features turned on? Note differences between that and other PC's

Comment: I tested with a key remap software and to detect the ALTGR  I got this key: **arrow left E0_48**